# Kotlin: How do you make a new instance of a data class with changes

Tags: kotlin, object-construction

I have a kotlin data class:

```
data class MyCats (
) {
    val name: String = "",
    val female: Boolean = false,
    val fixed: Boolean = false
}
```

As I understand Kotlin (still a newbie), I can instantiate this class and set all its parameters at once, such as

```
val morris = MyCats("Morris")
```

Now let's say that I get morris fixed.  I can't change the value of `morris.fixed` because it's a val.  But I can create a new object.  How do I make a new object with all the values of morris, but with the fixed set to true?

Sure, I could go through and do everything manually, but I thought the whole point of Kotlin was to save programmers from that sort of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the [`copy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying) function:

`morris.copy(fixed = true)`

Comment: How did you know that? What other not-reserved-words do I need to know to use kotlin? My eyes must have glazed over while reading that part. The docs are currently 619 pages long (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-docs.pdf); it'll take a while to memorize it.

Comment: Don't necessarily try to memorize it, just focus on learning to look up relevant documentation efficiently.

Comment: Or just let your IDE show you all the available methods and extension functions!  If you're using IntelliJ, type `morris.` and hit Ctrl+Space, and see what pops up…